# Someone trying to get into my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, nginx, server

I hosted my Rails application last week. Today I was going through our log file and noticed lots of request like this.

```
I, [2016-03-14T00:42:18.501703 #21223]  INFO -- : Started GET "/testproxy.php" for 185.49.14.190 at 2016-03-14 00:42:18 -0400
F, [2016-03-14T00:42:18.510616 #21223] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/testproxy.php"):
```

Someone is trying to go to `testproxy.php` from different ip address. Some ip are from poland and others from hongkong. Am I getting attacked by someone. What are my options to protect myself.

Here are other outputs from log file:

```
I, [2016-03-14T03:09:24.945467 #15399]  INFO -- : Started GET "/clientaccesspolicy.xml" for 107.22.223.242 at 2016-03-14 03:09:24 -0400
F, [2016-03-14T03:09:24.949328 #15399] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/clientaccesspolicy.xml"):
```

Different ip address:

```
I, [2016-03-14T16:03:47.793731 #15399]  INFO -- : Started GET "/testproxy.php" for 178.216.200.48 at 2016-03-14 16:03:47 -0400
F, [2016-03-14T16:03:47.818519 #15399] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/testproxy.php"):
```

`search.php`

```
I, [2016-03-14T19:41:14.261843 #15399]  INFO -- : Started GET "/forum/search.php" for 164.132.161.67 at 2016-03-14 19:41:14 -0400
F, [2016-03-14T19:41:14.266563 #15399] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/forum/search.php"):
```

`forum/index.php`

```
I, [2016-03-15T10:54:55.254785 #26469]  INFO -- : Started GET "/forum/index.php" for 164.132.161.56 at 2016-03-15 10:54:55 -0400
F, [2016-03-15T10:54:55.266456 #26469] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/forum/index.php"):
```

`phpmyadim/scripts/setup.php`

```
I, [2016-03-15T13:21:36.862918 #26469]  INFO -- : Started GET "/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php" for 103.25.73.234 at 2016-03-15 13:21:36 -0400
F, [2016-03-15T13:21:36.867050 #26469] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/phpMyAdmin/scripts/setup.php"):
```

`another setup.php`

```
I, [2016-03-15T13:21:37.452097 #26469]  INFO -- : Started GET "/pma/scripts/setup.php" for 103.25.73.234 at 2016-03-15 13:21:37 -0400
F, [2016-03-15T13:21:37.453647 #26469] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/pma/scripts/setup.php"):
```

`myadmin/scripts/setup.php`

```
I, [2016-03-15T13:21:38.034283 #26469]  INFO -- : Started GET "/myadmin/scripts/setup.php" for 103.25.73.234 at 2016-03-15 13:21:38 -0400
F, [2016-03-15T13:21:38.041563 #26469] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/myadmin/scripts/setup.php"):
```

and lots of other stuff. Please tell me how can I protect myself from those attacks.

Comment: They're not going to do anything unless you have PHP. If you want to suppress these, why not set up a server rule to ignore all `.php` type requests?

Comment: @tadman I was thinking about blocking the ip address. What do you think?

Comment: Using something like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) might be a solution.

Comment: @tadman thank you. I have setup following rules to `nginx`. Hopefull tat will do the trick. location ~ (\.php|.aspx|.asp|myadmin) {
    return 404;
}

Comment: yes! looks like a bot trying to exploit known endpoints for PHP applications -- tough luck with that :P You could try to drop things fast if you see the suffix .php -- e.g. either in the NginX config or in a Middleware. NginX config would be preferable.

Comment: Yes, it looks like a bot. You should expect this sort of thing with any public-facing app. This is what security is *for.*

Comment: If you got it working, might be worth adding the configuration you used as an answer.

Comment: Yeah this is common OP.  You'll want to block them at the firewall.  At my last company we'd get tons of chinese bots attacking so the ip block list was rather lengthy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is commonplace when you are running a public server. Here is an excerpt of my home server's auth.log:

```
Mar 14 19:22:36 hotdog sshd[65937]: Received disconnect from 181.214.92.11:  11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 14 19:22:37 hotdog sshd[65939]: Invalid user ubnt from 181.214.92.11
Mar 14 19:22:37 hotdog sshd[65939]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ubnt [preauth]
Mar 14 19:22:37 hotdog sshd[65939]: Received disconnect from 181.214.92.11: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 14 19:22:38 hotdog sshd[65941]: Invalid user support from 181.214.92.11
Mar 14 19:22:38 hotdog sshd[65941]: input_userauth_request: invalid user support [preauth]
Mar 14 19:22:38 hotdog sshd[65941]: Received disconnect from 181.214.92.11: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 14 19:22:39 hotdog sshd[65943]: Invalid user oracle from 181.214.92.11
Mar 14 19:22:39 hotdog sshd[65943]: input_userauth_request: invalid user oracle [preauth]
Mar 14 19:22:39 hotdog sshd[65943]: Received disconnect from 181.214.92.11: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 14 19:22:40 hotdog sshd[65945]: Received disconnect from 181.214.92.11: 11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 14 19:24:04 hotdog sshd[65947]: fatal: Read from socket failed: Operation timed out [preauth]
Mar 14 20:01:19 hotdog sshd[66032]: Received disconnect from 183.3.202.102: 11:  [preauth]
Mar 14 20:40:17 hotdog sshd[66092]: Invalid user cacti from 199.217.117.71
Mar 14 20:40:17 hotdog sshd[66092]: input_userauth_request: invalid user cacti [preauth]
Mar 14 20:40:17 hotdog sshd[66092]: Connection closed by 199.217.117.71 [preauth]
Mar 14 21:32:09 hotdog sshd[66188]: Received disconnect from 183.3.202.102: 11:  [preauth]
Mar 14 22:01:59 hotdog sshd[66256]: Invalid user user1 from 199.217.117.71
Mar 14 22:01:59 hotdog sshd[66256]: input_userauth_request: invalid user user1 [preauth]
Mar 14 22:02:00 hotdog sshd[66256]: Connection closed by 199.217.117.71 [preauth]
Mar 14 22:17:57 hotdog sshd[66280]: Did not receive identification string from 14.182.117.161
```

As you can see people are constantly trying to break into my server, by guessing a username. Since the server only accepts publickey login, not password, I believe myself to be fairly secure from these particular attacks.

The same applies to your PHP files. They are trying to find a php endpoint which they can run some canned exploit on. You can use tools like **fail2ban** which help with rate-limiting. But really these attacks will always be present on a public server. The only way is to ensure your software can resist attacks.

Some general common-sense tips:

- Don't run more services than you need, as any one service could open your server to attack. Check which ports you have open with nmap.
- Check that your apache/nginx config doesn't allow execute of more (PHP) files than necessary.
- Update your software continuously. Most of these attacks are automated and thus rely on published exploits in common packages.

Answer (score 0):

I have the IP address `183.3.202.102` and some others from the same subnet quite frequently appear in the log of one of my honeypots.

It suddenly stopped though. I guess someone finally submitted an abuse report and had them banned.